How to not abbreviate an entry in biblatex with only a last name from Zotero export
I am using Zotero to create my bibliography in the file references.bib.
I want to use the IEEE style where the author's name is abbreviated.
Now I have one bibentry where I want to cite "The MathWorks Inc." as an author. For this, I entered "The MathWorks Inc." as last name in Zotero and leave the first name field empty.
The resulting references.bib file looks like this:
@article{lastname_title_nodate,
title = {Title},
author = {Lastname, Firstname},
}
@misc{the_mathworks_inc_matlab_nodate,
    title = {{MATLAB}},
    author = {The MathWorks Inc.},
}

main.tex:
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{the_mathworks_inc_matlab_nodate}
\cite{lastname_title_nodate}

\printbibliography
\end{document}

Here comes the problem: the entry for "The MathWorks Inc." is still interpreted as last name "Inc." and first name "The MathWorks". The resulting bibliography entry's author is "T. M. Inc.".

Some solutions I found solve this by modifying the references file (1, 2), but I want to still be able to update my references.bib file through Zotero, without having to change it every time. I also tried to add special characters in Zotero, but they get "translated" into latex commands. Is there any quick solution?

use an additional pair of braces: author = {{The MathWorks Inc.}},

As Ulrike Fischer wrote in the comments, author = {The MathWorks Inc.}, is simply not acceptable input here if you don't want the name to be treated like the name of a person that is split into family and given names, you need to "protect" the name with curly braces in the .bib file.
author = {{The MathWorks Inc.}},

See also Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full).
In Zotero you need to switch the name to "single-field mode" when you enter corporate authors (there is a small icon to the right of the name). This should then export the name to .bib correctly. See https://www.zotero.org/support/kb/name_parsing#field_mode.

I found this youtube video showing the process of switching the field mode: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZ5b-Ls6QUw

Just one click in Zotero was what I was needed. Thank you very much!
